# Not getting the required output in accessing web service by HTTP

Tags: android

I am trying to convert use a web service to convert celcius to farenheit and not getting the required output. can anyone help me out...here is my code.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter("Celsius", "32");

        HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"); 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext); 

       tv.setText(response.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is it that you are currently getting?

Comment: Did you try this url: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit

Comment: I am getting - org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f89068 - this kind of output while i should get some integer or double value kindly help me out...

Comment: @cularis - yes i had tried this url before also, but that was with ksoap2 i want to do it with HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`HttpParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html) is not a collection of query/GET params. It's used for "HTTP protocol and framework parameters" as the docs put it. So, in case of a GET request, you add query params by either appending "?Celsius=32" to that URL or use the [`Uri.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html). For POST request, you have to use the `setEntity` method. Like in this example ([source](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

// add POST params
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foo", "123"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bar", "456"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Secondly, in order to read the response as a `String` you need something like this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
String json = convertStreamToString(content);

// ...

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    Reader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputReader, 8192);
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    try {
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        string.append(line + "\n");
      }
    } finally {
      input.close();
    }

    return string.toString();
}
```